# Combination of Auto Comma and Auto Sum in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

i have this syntax where i want to combine the script of having a textbox autocomma and auto result whenever i input values. is there a better way to do this?

```js
          $('.numeric_value').keyup(function() {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.numeric_value').each(function() {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
            $('#total').val(sum);
        });
       
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[data-type='number']").keyup(function(event){
          // skip for arrow keys
          if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
              event.preventDefault();
          }
          var $this = $(this);
          var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "");
          var num2 = num.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
          console.log(num2);
          // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.
          $this.val(num2);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="number" class="numeric_value" autofocus="autofocus">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>+</label>
       <input type="number" class="numeric_value">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>=</label>
       <input type="text" data-type="number" class="form-control" id="total" disabled>
      </div>
     </form>
      <!-- <input type="number" class="numeric_value" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=Comma(this.value);"> -->
       <input class="numeric_value" id="id_step2-number_2" name="step2-number_2" type="text" data-type="number">
```

Comment: `keyup()` is always a better way to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey i wanted to combine both that the result will get a steady output whenever you input 1,0000 it will result to NAN, i mean the last input field

Comment: the output wont accept this as a valid number.. how can i adjust this so that the combination will be possible

Comment: Add this code on `Script` in 6th line - `sum.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")`

Comment: @UtkarshDubey nice, it works well. i think you should post it as an answer here rather than a comment i cannot check on it.. one last bro how about the numeric value itself where can i add an auto comma?

Comment: `type="number"` not allow character `,`. Therefore you have to change type from `number` to `text`.

Comment: @UtkarshDubey what if i use data-type="number"? would it still not count?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154104/discussion-between-utkarsh-dubey-and-hanthony-tagam).